# Why can non-coders take the Developer Survey this year?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2021

In last year's Developer Survey [I noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393801/what-is-the-point-of-the-third-question-in-the-survey-if-i-already-indicated-tha) that non-coders are prevented from completing the survey; after providing enough information to show that they are non-coders (and some additional information) the survey ends and they receive the following message:

> The Stack Overflow Developer Survey is for those who write code as a hobbyist, student, or professional. You indicated that none of these describe you. Thank you  for your interest and click here to learn more about Stack Overflow, the world's largest community of developers

[image: Screenshot showing the message that explains that the survey is only for people who code]

I just tried the same thing with this year's survey, and I was able to make it through the entire survey. This is despite the fact that I answered the first question about my coding habits with "None of these":

[image: Screenshot showing my answer to the first question]

Now I suppose that it could have been possible that this year Stack Overflow wanted input from non-coders as well, but this does not seem to be the case because the link that I followed to get to the survey was in a banner notification on a different network site which explicitly said that they want input from coders:

[image: Screenshot of banner stating that input is wanted from people who code]

It might also have been assumed that a non-coder would get stuck on one of the later questions which ask about the details of your coding experience, and thus would not be able to complete the survey. However, every other question related to actual coding was a non-required question, so it was possible to get to the end of the survey without providing any coding information.

While I doubt that many non-coders would bother to complete the survey, it is apparently possible that they can do so (whether maliciously or not). This, of course, would dilute the accuracy of the data, unless all data associated with someone who selected "None of these" in the first answer is automatically discarded. If that is the case, though, it would be courteous to inform the people taking the survey that there is no point in doing so, to prevent them from needlessly wasting their time.

(In point of fact, I did not submit my survey, precisely because of the above mentioned concerns. It is possible, then, that when clicking on the submit button I would have received some form of rejection notice that I am now unaware of, and the survey would not go through. However, if that is the case, then I should receive that notice after my answer to the first question indicating that I am not a coder, instead of after spending time on the entire rest of the survey.)

Comment: I think a lot is changed this year in survey. But if this is not a bug from the survey then I think it doesn't make sense to include "None of these" into the question itself. And if it is not a bug in survey then this raised question makes a sense.

Comment: I don't think "None of the above" means "I don't code" – it just means none of the options applies most prominently, e.g. people who are developers by profession and also code a lot as a hobby.

Comment: You have to choose the option that *best* describes you, @MisterMiyagi. If two of the options describe you, your choice cannot be "None of the above".

Comment: @CodyGray Two of these option describe me *equally well*. I've picked one but it's hard to say it's best compared to the other. I can very well see others pick "None of the above" in such situations.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Note that, as established in the first part of the question, last year picking that option was indeed taken to mean that you don’t code, and you couldn’t take the rest of the survey.

Comment: I would say that was a bug last year then. As others mentioned, "None of these" doesn't mean "I don't code".

Comment: @Alex It's nice they said that last year. Just, no one said it to me and I guess many lots other people. So I don't assume all people voted in accordance with something someone said somewhen somewhere.

Comment: @hek2mgl if someone does not code by profession, sometimes as a job task, via hobby, or during studies, what is left there to be that does not mean "I do not code", though?

Comment: @OlegValter As mentioned above, "more than one". Things like privately learning don't quite fit the categories either.

Comment: @OlegValter "I'm a teacher for coding at school", for example? .. What I want to say is that the survey question wasn't well phrased for the purpose it seemed to be meant for. Right would have been: "I don't code".

Comment: Why was the survey changed? Because someone looked at the options and said "hey, that last one doesn't necessarily mean *'I don't code'"?* I can imagine other reasons, such as "never mind telling coders about coders, we make money telling advertisers about visitors, so *gather it all!"*

Comment: @MisterMiyagi isn't "privately learning" the same as "hobby"? You are either doing that (learning) for your future profession or out of genuine interest (as a hobby). Don't get me wrong, I wish this question allowed multi-choice like "I code for work & as a hobby", just not sure if the volume of concept in the "other" option is more than 0

Comment: @hek2mgl that's a good point, I am not sure any of the above covers this (probably "code sometimes as part of my work" is close, but that's probably a stretch). And agreed that formulated as you propose would be better.

Comment: @Beta But they didn’t actually change the survey. The choices are exactly the same as last year; the only difference is in whether you can continue with the rest of the survey.

Comment: With regard to the possibility that “None of these” is meant to indicate that you code in some capacity not covered by the other choices, I would note that in fact the message last year didn’t say that you can’t take the survey because you don’t code at all; it said that you can’t take the survey because you don’t code *as a hobbyist, student, or professional*, i.e. the categories covered by the other choices.

Comment: @Alex: They changed the underlying logic of the survey, the decision tree. To say that *"they didn't actually change the survey"...* That's the kind of thing I like to wait 24 hours before responding to.

Comment: @OlegValter Not with the current wording. People just privately training to be a developer but not currently being employed as such won't fit the student nor professional nor hobbyist part. Mind, I agree that the volume of that category probably isn't worth loosing any sleep.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi don't disagree with that, was in that category myself when I started (considered myself a hobbyist back then, though). Not that I think this is important, but it seems like Alex raised a good point - because it seems like SE thinks the "none of these" means "I do not code".

Comment: Just wondering, when you're at a restaurant and you see two of your favourite dishes on the menu, and you have trouble deciding what to eat. Do you not eat anything at all that night? Or do you just pick one of the two at random? If you're both just pick the one you're more likely to talk about to friends, as its probably the one you identify with more. Also to me (non native english speaker) "None of these"  would imply not coding, otherwise I would expect either "multiple of these" or "Other coding (related) activies"

Comment: maybe I was Developer, now I Am Manager

Comment: "This, of course, would dilute the accuracy of the data (...)" this can be solved quite easily, e.g. showing 2 set of results or allowing user to view the results which contain or not the response from non-coder. On the other hand, if it's really about the accuracy of the data, there's more thing more complex to deal with to cleanse up the "raw" data. I consider myself a coder by profession, yet there are parts of the survey making be a bit confused and there are chances that my response is not totally accurate.

Comment: @GovindSingh your option would be "I used to be a developer by profession but no longer am" or if you code as a manager occasionally: "I am not primarily a developer, but I write code sometimes as part of my work"

Comment: I believe every scenario I've seen mentioned here, where the respondent does any coding whatsoever, has an obvious and correct choice from the list. But it seems like folks are getting wrapped around the axle of a Buridan paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass

Comment: I'm gonna side with @MisterMiyagi here - "none of the above" in this context doesn't really imply that the responder doesn't code. Having an explicit "I don't code" option would've been better, but that aside, there are legitimate reasons why none of the options fit. Oleg posted a comment earlier that actually backs this point up: "isn't "privately learning" the same as "hobby"" - the fact that that's a question indicates doubt. And guess what, not all responders automatically associate their learning with it being a hobby. It's all a matter of subjective interpretations

Comment: about where the line goes for various categories, and unless you can get every single respondent to get in on the same definitions, "none of the above" does some times mean "I code, but none of the above fit". Again, I'd rather see an "I don't code" option here if we care about leaving non-coders out of the survey

Comment: How many people who aren't coders would find the survey and bother filling out the whole survey

Comment: @qwr It’s advertised on the rest of the network.

Comment: Was... was there ever a problem with non-coders taking the _Developer_ Survey on StackOverflow to completion? Was StackOverflow having to manually discard too many survey results from confused python owners, coffee aficionados, or grandmas thinking this was a knitting website? Because if not, then the obvious answer is that this is a fix, someone in charge woke up enough to realize that there was never a good reason to block non-coders from completing the survey in the first place.

Comment: I used to officially code full time, but spent a lot of time doing non-code things like evaluating software and maintaining servers.  Now I officially devops full time but spend a lot of time writing scripts and even some application programs.  Was I a coder then?  Am I now?  I'm glad the survey doesn't make me try to decide whether I'm a coder or not in order to participate, because most days I don't actually know.

Comment: @WayneConrad Sounds like the second option in the list describes you best then. But at the same time it sound like you purposely don't want to put yourself in any kind of box, at which point the "none of the above" option is pretty much what you would want to pick. It might be "I'm not any kind of programmer!", it might also be "none of your business" or "I don't want to decide".